# Modify an array object that construts a table and then post that object

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to post an array object that constructs a table. I want to from the table to modify(add new data) the data and post it.

Code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="cus in postObj.custs">
 <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="postObj.custs[$index].principal"/></td>
 <td>{{cus.Name}}</td>
 <td>{{cus.Phone}}</td>
 <td>{{cus.AddPre}}</td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="postObj.custs[$index].relation"/></td>
 <td>
     <button ng-click="deleteCus(cus)">Delete</button>
 </td>
```

In the above code the  tags inside the  is the field for new values.
But when I console.log() the object the new objects are never there. So what can be done with this?

Comment: can you add some code with your posting procedure?

Comment: your ng-model could be cus.principal and cus.relation when you post your new object you have to send  postObj.custs or the scecific parts of your array